# How do I add an outline to my label in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, label, outline

I'm new to Stackoverflow.
I am currently developing a mobile application using XCode for iOS.
However I'm trying to set add a white outline/stroke to my label but I do not know hot to. I have tried searching these forums but could not find any solution in swift.
I have tried using the shadow property, but it's not satisfactory.
How do I add an outline to my label in Swift?
Edit: The text should look like the text in this picture: http://cf.chucklesnetwork.com/items/7/5/7/4/4/original/yo-dawg-i-heard-you-like-captions-so-i-put-captions-of-captions.jpg

Comment: u can set border for the label

Comment: please post image of your requirement. layer.border will set border

Comment: Welcome! Can you please share a bit of your current code to walk over. Like the label you have mentioned etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Outline UILabel text in UILabel Subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40575408/outline-uilabel-text-in-uilabel-subclass)

Comment: I would like my text to look like the text in this picture:  http://cf.chucklesnetwork.com/items/7/5/7/4/4/original/yo-dawg-i-heard-you-like-captions-so-i-put-captions-of-captions.jpg

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use `NSAttributedString`, set `strokeColor` and `strokeWidth`  to set outline and `foregroundColor` to set text color. Try this:

```
let attrString = NSAttributedString(
    string: "Write Something with Outline",
    attributes: [
        NSAttributedStringKey.strokeColor: UIColor.black, 
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, 
        NSAttributedStringKey.strokeWidth: -2.0, 
        NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)
    ]
)
yourLabel.attributedText = attrString
```

This will look like below:

[image]

Comment: Please let me know where are you getting this error?

Comment: Thanks that fixed it

Comment: Happy that it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this [OutlinedLabel](https://github.com/adrianorezena/OutlinedLabel). Unlike most examples, it actually outlines the text.
And you can even gradient the outline.

Just set the outline color and the line width:

```
label.outlineColor = .white
label.outlineWidth = 7
```

This will look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vh7jm.png)